# What is the next number in the last group

Tags: pattern-recognition

there. I came across a number pattern problem like the one in the following picture. Does anyone happen to know what the ? stands for? Or how can we calculate the number? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third number in each sequence is the sum of the squares of the previous 2.
$$2^2+6^2=4+36=40$$
$$3^2+7^2=9+49=58$$
$$6^2+5^2=36+25=61$$

Using this rule, we can do it for the missing number:
$$2^2+3^2=4+9=13$$

So the correct answer is (A) 13

Comment: Thank you very much, DarkAtom. That surely is the pattern.